# Mac installer signed with install4j is unsigned

Tags: macos, code-signing, install4j

Using install4j v5.1.14 on Windows 7, I sign our Mac OS X installer with our Comodo certificate. The build output reports that the installer is signed and there are no errors. However, when I download the installer to my Mac running Yosemite and try to run it, I get a warning that the installer app is from an unidentified developer. The security settings on the Mac are set to the default (Mac App Store and identified developers).

When I run the codesign command on the installer app, it returns the following.

```
Executable=/Volumes/CTAT/Cognitive Tutor Authoring Tools Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
Identifier=com.install4j.2755-2489-4896-4417.1986
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=627 flags=0x0(none) hashes=24+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=71d7b98e105e76c12cbe638b67448028d5d593f3
Signature size=5447
Authority=CMU - Cognitive Tutor Authoring Tools Group
Authority=COMODO Code Signing CA 2
Authority=UTN-USERFirst-Object
Authority=AddTrust External CA Root
Signed Time=Jan 23, 2015, 12:36:01 PM
Info.plist entries=25
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=15
Internal requirements count=1 size=36
```

If the certificate is valid, why does it say it's from an unidentified developer? Does Gatekeeper only recognize certs signed with an Apple Developer ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Gatekeeper only recognize certs signed with an Apple Developer ID?

Yes, you need an Apple Developer ID certificate. Other certificates will not be recognized by gatekeeper.